# Error Y_pred This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test,  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

X_train= X_train.reshape(-1, 1)


Y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're not calling the `fit`. You need to call it after declaring `LinearRegression` model as following:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
X_train= X_train.reshape(-1, 1)

lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)  # fit should be used here
Y_pred = lr.predict(X_test) # prediction stage
```

Comment: Si me di cuenta lo agregué y funcionó gracias

Comment: ¡Siempre te esperamos!